# How can i use 'jQuery TE' plugin in my html,css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Already i have included the following line in my .html file in `<head>` tag after main.js file.

```
<script src="js/jquery-te-1.4.0.js"></script>
```

Now how can i proceed further?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean of `Now how can i proceed further?`.

Comment: How can i call the methods in my javascript? For ex: $('.div').methodname({  });

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML

```
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

and in your script

```
$("textarea").jqte();
```

Comment: I am getting it in the form of text not in the form of images for color and fonts etc. for ex: abcdef abcdef abcdef .... and colors are displayed horizontally. Iam not getting the format which is in the jquery-te.png of that plugin.